# Read Application.mk information from an apk

Tags: android, android-ndk, apk, cpu-architecture, abi

I would like to know if there is any way to extract from an APK file the Application.mk information.

I particularly interested getting from the APK the [supported CPU ABI's](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)

if it's not possible reading the Application.mk file, then what is the right way knowing for sure what ABI's the apk is built for?

Comment: You mean from Android or from a tool on a pc?

Comment: my application's server need to extract this information programatically from exiting file

Comment: so you have an application server that analyze an apk? Or receive requests from an app and you should take care of the abi?

Comment: server scraping apk files from google play.   the client app is an application strore (exactly like google play..)

Comment: You should use apktool, or simply unzip the apk, then inside the lib folder you will find a directory for each supported abi. If lib is empty it means that it is supported by all ABI

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought also, but it fails the the reality test:  I have an apk that contains armeabi-v7a for Facebook application, but it crashes on unsupported ABI exception when running on device declaring CPU_ABI = x86 and CPU_ABI2 = armeabi-v7a

Comment: this the apk : https://cdn-root.s3.amazonaws.com/apk%2F36769C46D59859CD%2Fcom.facebook.katana_23_4968884a17c87d97b6ca592f00c839f527eee509.apk

Comment: it happens on Azus Zenfone running android 4.4

Comment: Really strange that a device declares both armeabi and x86. It should not! The set of instruction is really different, so I believe it is a bug of the device FW.

Comment: thanks. can you answer officially my question and write the summary that what we spoke, so I could accept you answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool that you can use server side to analyse an apk are unzip or, if you want to go deeper, apktool. When you unzip the apk you'll find a folder for each supported abi inside the lib folder of the uncompressed apk (x86, armeabi-v7a, etc.). The list of folder is the list of supported ABI, so you can get the information there. By code you can get the list of supported ABI of a device using the [CPU_ABI for device running pre Lollipop](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#CPU_ABI) and [SUPPORTED_ABIS for devices running Android 21+](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SUPPORTED_ABIS).

About your question: the Application.mk is used to build the native library, so it's not zipped within the apk.